# Replace an iMac superdrive with one pulled from a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, optical-drive

I have an old Mid 2009 13" MacBook Pro (unibody) that I'm not using anymore. I've already pulled the superdrive out of it.

I also have a 2009 27" iMac that I *am* using. The superdrive on it is no longer working for various reasons, and needs to be replaced. I'm comfortable opening the iMac and replacing it, I've done it before.

Can I use the drive from my '09 Pro in my iMac?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is likely form factor more than anything else, though Apple *is* famous for custom connectors...

I would look through the take-a-parts on fixit.com on those two units and see if they look the same.

Also a bit of googling for a replacement drive for both and seeing if the part numbers are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Simply; if it fits & has the same connectors [or you can find alternatives in the machine] you can use it.

Apple transitioned from PATA to SATA for Superdrives later than for HDs, though I'm not sure when that transition was completed.
My 08 Mac Pro uses PATA for the Superdrive, SATA for the HDs - so I found a spare SATA port inside & wired it across to a brand new SATA Superdrive. I used a simple PATA>SATA power cable converter & added it to the existing power.
New drive is ⅓ the thickness of the old one, but still matches to the slot - so all is fine.

However, you can't go the other way; you can't patch a PATA drive into an SATA machine.

If it comes to buying a new one… PATA Superdrives are about $100 - ouch!
SATA equivalents you can get for about $15.